# Error in socket client program

Tags: c, sockets, client

I have already created one client server program and already run it successfully.The code is written below.But the `while (1)` loop is not clear to me and I am not sure why I am using `fgets` here, why the flag is set as zero? A detailed explanation will help.

**Socket Client Code:**

```
    while (1)

    {

        fgets(input, BUFFER, stdin);
        send (sock, input, strlen(input),0);

        len = recv(sock, output, BUFFER, 0);
        output [len]='\0';
        printf("%s\n", output);
    }

    close(sock);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is strln() is not available in your program. Use `strlen()` instead of `strln()`.

**Explanation for while(1):**
Here the while(1) which get the input from the user and send to the another socket. The recv wait for the message which is send by the another socket. This is just sending and receiving the message.

Use some test condition to break the statement, like `if(strcmp(input,"END") == 0) break;` Else it continue the work again and again.

Comment: Hope you will edit your answer according to the qestion.

Answer (score 2):

I think typo in your code

use [strlen](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strlen.htm) instead `strln`.

**EDIT**

In `while(1)`,

```
fgets(input, BUFFER, stdin);
```

This line gets user input and stores it in `input` buffer upto maximum length `BUFFER`.

```
send (sock, input, strlen(input),0);
```

This line sends packets ( here `input` ) to the connected socket with descriptor `sock`

```
len = recv(sock, output, BUFFER, 0);
```

This line  receives a message from connected socket with descriptor `sock` and upon successful reception of data, the length of received data returns to `len`. Received data will store in `output` buffer and `output` buffer size is `BUFFER`.

```
output [len]='\0';
```

End the received data with `NULL Terminator`.

So, it basically gets data from the user, sends it to connected socket and receives response from that connected socket.

Also you aked that `why the flag is set to 0` means this flags specify influence the behavior of the **recv/send** functions. But if you don't want to use any flag then simply make it **`0`**.

You can check how other values of flag use full for [recv](http://www.irietools.com/iriepascal/progref386.html) and [send](http://www.irietools.com/iriepascal/progref388.html#ws2_send_send) function.

Comment: Please edit your answer according to the queston.

Comment: @user3751012 Have edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use `strlen(input)`. You are missing an e.

Comment: Please check the question again.